Similarity between Combinatorial Series and Recursions
I was evaluating the sum $$a_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} {2n+1 \choose 2k+1} 2^{3k}$$
The method I went about was treating $$a_n = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} \sum_{k=0}^{n} {2n+1 \choose 2k+1} (2\sqrt{2})^{2k+1} \\ b_n = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} \sum_{k=0}^{n} {2n+1 \choose 2k} (2\sqrt{2})^{2k}$$
Obviously, by the binomial theorem $$a_n + b_n = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} (2\sqrt{2}+1)^{2n+1} \\ a_n - b_n = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} (2\sqrt{2}-1)^{2n+1}$$
This gives a closed form for both $a_n$ and $b_n$ as
$$a_n = \frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}} \left((2\sqrt{2}+1)^{2n+1} + (2\sqrt{2}-1)^{2n+1} \right) \\ b_n = \frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}} \left((2\sqrt{2}+1)^{2n+1} - (2\sqrt{2}-1)^{2n+1} \right)$$
But this form seemed familiar to the general solution of a homogeneous second order recursion, the recursions being: $$a_{n+2} - 18a_{n+1} + 49a_n = 0, a_0 = 1, a_1 = 11 \\ b_{n+2} - 18b_{n+1} + 49b_n = 0, b_0 = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}, b_1 = \frac{25}{2\sqrt{2}}$$
Is there a more "elegant" way to reach this recursion without finding the closed form of $a_n$ or $b_n$? (finding just the characteristic roots of the recursion also works)
Also, to what extent can we generalize this?

Let $A(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ be the ordinary generating function.
Then
\begin{align}
A(z) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{2n+1}{2k+1} 2^{3k} z^n \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^{3k} \sum_{n=k}^\infty \binom{2n+1}{2k+1} z^n \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^{3k} z^k \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{2n+2k+1}{2k+1} z^n \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty (8z)^k \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{2n+2k+1}{2k+1} \sqrt{z}^{2n} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty (8z)^k \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1+(-1)^n}{2}\binom{n+2k+1}{2k+1} \sqrt{z}^n \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty (8z)^k \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n+2k+1}{2k+1} \sqrt{z}^n + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n+2k+1}{2k+1} (-\sqrt{z})^n\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty (8z)^k \left(\frac{1}{(1-\sqrt{z})^{2k+2}} + \frac{1}{(1+\sqrt{z})^{2k+2}}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2(1-\sqrt{z})^2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{8z}{(1-\sqrt{z})^2}\right)^k + \frac{1}{2(1+\sqrt{z})^2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{8z}{(1+\sqrt{z})^2}\right)^k \\
&= \frac{1}{2(1-\sqrt{z})^2}\cdot\frac{1}{1-8z/(1-\sqrt{z})^2} + \frac{1}{2(1+\sqrt{z})^2}\cdot\frac{1}{1-8z/(1+\sqrt{z})^2} \\
&= \frac{1-7 z}{1-18z+49z^2},
\end{align}
from which the denominator immediately yields the recursion $a_n-18a_{n-1}+49a_{n-2}=0$.
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant-recursive_sequence#In_terms_of_generating_functions for the general result about rational generating functions.

You may introduce a formal variable $j$ s.t. $j^2=1$, then for any $x$ (in particular, $x=2 \sqrt 2$) it holds that
$$
a_n+jb_n = \sum\limits_{k} \binom{2n+1}{k} x^{k-1} j^k =x^{-1}(1+xj)^{2n+1}.
$$
On the other hand,
$$
(1+xj)^{2n+1} = (1+xj)^2(1+xj)^{2n-1} = (1+2xj+x^2)
(1+xj)^{2n-1},
$$
which means that
$$
a_n + jb_n = (1+2xj+x^2)(a_{n-1}+jb_{n-1}),
$$
thus
$$
\begin{cases}
a_n = (1+x^2) a_{n-1} + 2x b_{n-1}, \\
b_n = (1+x^2) b_{n-1} + 2x a_{n-1}.
\end{cases}
$$
From the first equation, we have
$$
2x b_{n} = a_n-(1+x^2) a_{n-1}.
$$
Putting it instead of $b_{n-1}$ in the second equation and multiplying it with $2x$, we now also get
$$
2xb_n = (1+x^2)a_n -(1-x^2)^2a_{n-1}.
$$
Finally, putting it back into first equation, we get
$$
a_n = 2(1+x^2)a_{n-1}-(1-x^2)^2a_{n-2}.
$$
For $x=2\sqrt 2$, it is $a_n = 18 a_{n-1} - 49 a_{n-2}$.

Also an even more direct and simple explanation here is that the system in matrix form rewrites as
$$
\begin{pmatrix} a_n \\ b_n \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1+x^2 & 2x \\ 2x & 1+x^2 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}a_{n-1} \\ b_{n-1} \end{pmatrix},
$$
and its characteristic polynomial is $\lambda^2-2(1+x^2)\lambda+(1-x^2)^2$.
Why is it relevant at all? Well, because on one hand we have
$$
\begin{pmatrix}a_n \\ b_n \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1+x^2 & 2x \\ 2x & 1+x^2 \end{pmatrix}^n \begin{pmatrix} a_0 \\ b_0 \end{pmatrix},
$$
on the other hand, by Cayley-Hamilton theorem, any matrix satisfies its own characteristic polynomial.
